# How can a DataFrame be shifted to the nearest time index to the one specified?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I have a DataFrame of values recorded and the index set to DatetimeIndex. A value is recorded approximately every 15 minutes.

I want to add a new column that is the fractional difference of the current value from a value 24 hours previously. Since the values are recorded *approximately* every fifteen minutes, I want to shift to the time index that is closest to 24 hours previously. If I try to do this exactly, I end up with a whole lot of `NaN`s:

```
df["value"] / df["value"].shift(freq = datetime.timedelta(days = -1))
```

How should this shift be done so that the shift is to the nearest possible time index to the one specified? Is there an alternative, easier way to think about this?

Here is an example that illustrates the issue:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [pd.Timestamp("2015-07-18 13:53:33.280"), 10],
        [pd.Timestamp("2015-07-19 13:54:03.330"), 20],
        [pd.Timestamp("2015-07-20 13:52:13.350"), 30],
        [pd.Timestamp("2015-07-21 13:56:03.126"), 40],
        [pd.Timestamp("2015-07-22 13:53:51.747"), 50],
        [pd.Timestamp("2015-07-23 13:53:29.346"), 60]
    ],
    columns = [
        "datetime",
        "value"
    ]
)

df.index = df["datetime"]
del df["datetime"]
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.values)

df["change"] = df["value"] / df["value"].shift(freq = datetime.timedelta(days = -1))
```

Comment: Where is your data?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I am trying to avoid cluttering up the page with data. I hope that the question is fairly clear and succinct. Example timestamps would be like `2017-03-09 14:36:06.516166` and `2017-03-09 14:51:07.661818`.

Comment: Well, without data, users will be forced to take shots in the dark :-( A good approach would be to post the first 5-10 rows of only the most important columns :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Ok, I'll put together a quick example.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Right, I've added example code. :)

Comment: Thanks for this. One more question. Does your actual data have one reading every 15 minutes?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes it does. I've made this example data to avoid lots of clutter. The goal, as I see it currently, is to shift to the time index *closest* to 24 hours different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add one day to the index then use `pd.DataFrame.reindex` with `method='nearest'`

```
df / df.set_index(df.index + pd.offsets.Day()).reindex(df.index, method='nearest')

                            value
2015-07-18 13:53:33.280  1.000000
2015-07-19 13:54:03.330  2.000000
2015-07-20 13:52:13.350  1.500000
2015-07-21 13:56:03.126  1.333333
2015-07-22 13:53:51.747  1.250000
2015-07-23 13:53:29.346  1.200000
```

---

You can provide another offset as a tolerance on the `method='nearest'`

```
df / df.set_index(df.index + pd.offsets.Day()).reindex(
    df.index, method='nearest', tolerance=pd.offsets.Hour(12))

                            value
2015-07-18 13:53:33.280       NaN
2015-07-19 13:54:03.330  2.000000
2015-07-20 13:52:13.350  1.500000
2015-07-21 13:56:03.126  1.333333
2015-07-22 13:53:51.747  1.250000
2015-07-23 13:53:29.346  1.200000
```

Comment: This is definitely more along the lines of what OP is looking for. Glad you decided to post an answer; I wasn't feeling good about mine, and I can peacefully remove it now. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ.  I appreciate the vote of confidence.

Comment: @BlandCorporation the only tricky part is understanding what you mean. You can fix that confusion by editing your post and including what you think the results should be. As you’ve described it, I thought what I’ve provided did exactly that. 60 divided by 50 which came ~24 hours earlier is 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

As follow your code:

```
df/df.shift(1)

                        value
2015-07-18 13:53:33.280 NaN
2015-07-19 13:54:03.330 2.000000
2015-07-20 13:52:13.350 1.500000
2015-07-21 13:56:03.126 1.333333
2015-07-22 13:53:51.747 1.250000
2015-07-23 13:53:29.346 1.200000
```

I can't sure if it is OK,but it seems to get the same answer.